# Alamofire HTTP sent twice SWIFT

Tags: swift, http, post, alamofire

every one, 
I'm having an issue with Alamofire 3.0, when I post data, it seems the data is being sent twice.
I looked up on the web, found that a bug about special caratères was fixed, but I still get the error.
Anyone has an idea. I'm using a parameter in the header called X-Authorization.

Here is an extract of the code i'm using:

```html
static func postData (url: String,token: String,params :Dictionary<String,AnyObject>){
        print("POSTINGGGGGG")
        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params,headers: ["X-Authorization": token])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let data): break
                    //let resultJSON = JSON(data).dictionaryValue
                   // print(data)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance,

Morgan

Comment: having this issue as well. No luck as of yet

Comment: Please use this
   let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
then  sessionManager.requst(.post/.get method)

Comment: @Mor did you found the solution? I am facing the same issue but hard luck.